# Visa necessary (German citizens) for visits to London after Brexit in 2021?

Tags: visas, german-citizens, brexit

Do German citizens need visa to visit London after Brexit, in 2021?

https://uk.diplo.de/uk-de/brexit-infos-deutsch/faq-informationen-brexit/610518 says until end of 2020 there is no visa necessary. But what after?

Comment: The fact that someone even sees this as a remote possibility shows how twisted the rhetoric media and politicians spew really is

Comment: Not sure what happens if there is a hard Brexit, all kinds of made agreements will be off then.

Comment: @Crayzdre: I do not follow the mainstream news. I just wanted to be on thw safe side before booking my trips.

Comment: @stephanmg From 1 October 2021, as it currently stands, you'll need a passport, and will only be able to stay for up to 6 months without further permission, but that's it

Comment: The `hard Brexit` was the term for a Brexit **without** a Withdrawal agreement (with its transition period). Brexit has occurred (2020-02-01) and the transition period is due to end on the 31st of December 2020. As far as *immigration controls* are concerned, it doesn't matter if the transition period ends with or without a **trade deal** (it will, however, effect the **customs controls** that will be introduced).

Comment: Recently, there was this question regarding visa requirements between continental Europe and the UK https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/160935/uk-citizen-married-to-an-irish-citizen-how-much-time-can-i-spend-in-the-eu-afte/160941?r=SearchResults#160941

Comment: @Willeke the importance of agreements in visa free travel is somewhat overestimated.  There are many cases where governments establish visa free travel unilaterally.

Comment: @MarkJohnson if the trade negotiations go spectacularly poorly, however, the current anticipated immigration regime could change for the worse.  It's very unlikely, but possible.

Comment: Who downvoting? How can I improve the question? Is it obvious?!

Comment: Wasn't me, but most visa requirements for western Europeans were abolished between 1947 and 1955, so why should they be reintroduced now?  [Visa policy of the United Kingdom - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_United_Kingdom#Non-visa_nationals) look for **Date of visa changes**

Comment: @MarkJohnson: Interesting. I do not really know why I was thinking this, was hearing only rumours about visa. Clearly I assumed passport should be still valid to enter UK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

Source: https://www.gov.uk/guidance/visiting-the-uk-from-1-january-2021#what-youll-need-to-enter-the-uk ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201115083325/https://www.gov.uk/guidance/visiting-the-uk-from-1-january-2021)):

> Visiting the UK from 1 January 2021: [...] EU, EEA and Swiss citizens will continue to be able to travel to the UK for holidays or short trips without needing a visa. You’ll be able to cross the UK border using a valid passport.
>
> You will not be able to use your EEA or Swiss national ID card to enter the UK from 1 October 2021.

Comment: What if a hard Brexit occurs?

Comment: @stephanmg sorry, no idea!

Comment: @stephanmg The quoted info is carved in stone, and so the "worst-case scenario"

Comment: @stephanmg nothing, really nothing.

Comment: Ah, I read to fast, yeah, then it's fine for me I guess. Thanks!

Comment: Another major change from the status quo is that EU/EEA/Swiss citizens won't have a _right_ to be admitted into the UK (freedom of movement). Whether or not you will be admitted will be at the discretion of border officers, just like it is now for EU citizens entering the US or for US citizens coming to the UK.

Comment: And of course **customs inspections** on both sides.

Comment: @Crazydre “carved in stone”? With the Brexiter lunatics currently in charge, nothing is carved in stone. Though I do expect them to cave in at the very last minute as usual, nothing is off the table...

Comment: @TooTea In practice, I can imagine the vetting will be simplified due to far less financial resources being needed to visit the UK. Like for Andorran/Monaco/San Marino nationals today.

Comment: It's worth stressing that this administration has contradicted itself _so_ many times that this advice might be out of date by January. A deal of some variety is rumoured soon, especially with Cummings resigning, with apparently the greatest hold-out being BoJo himself. Brexit continues to be one of those situations where I really, _really_ want to reload the save.

Comment: @JonathanReez I cannot access your thread/question.

Comment: @stephanmg It must have been deleted; I left a comment on it and that has disappeared.

Comment: @TripeHound okay. Well my question is settled, so that's okay.